# Generating gitlab flavored markdown from rmarkdown

Tags: r, gitlab, r-markdown

I want to generate from an rmarkdown file (using RStudio) a Gitlab flavored markdown(GFM), so the file is displayed properly on a gitlab server.

I am especially interested in having Latex formula to be displayed properly.

In the [gitlab documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/user/markdown.md#math) specify that the formulas should be written between $` and `$

```
 $`a^2+b^2=c^2`$
```

But [Rmarkdown](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf) require the $ $ synthax (no `)

```
 $a^2+b^2=c^2$
```

Currently I have tryied to create github flavored markdown with the following yaml in the preamble:

```
output:
  html_document: 
    keep_md: false
  md_document:
    variant: markdown_github
```

but when entering the following in my Rmd file:

```
$A=\displaystyle\sum_{b} c_b$
```

I get the following in the markdown:

```
*A* = ∑<sub>*b*</sub>*c*<sub>*b*</sub>
```

How can I configure my Rmarkdown or Rstudio so I will get this in the md file:

```
$`A=\displaystyle\sum_{b} c_b`$
```